# Markdown File not formatted propertly, preview pane is fine though (GitHub)

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, markdown

I've uploaded one Rmarkdown file to Github (as a .md file). At first, it was OK, but when i checked it a few days ago it was just out of format, just like it is now:

[image: wrong format]

But when i go to Edit>Preview on GitHub, it just shows as I expect it to behave (and as it was at the first time i uploaded this project and as my RmarkDown file is):

[image: the way it should be formatted]

Any tips on how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repo? Those pictures are of different sections of the doc, so it's inconclusive to say it isn't right because of something.

Comment: @r2evans Sure! https://github.com/gabrieloqm/multiple-regression-model/blob/master/multiple-regression-model.md

Comment: Interesting. This does not appear to be an [tag:r] issue, likely not [tag:git] or [tag:r-markdown]. Perhaps this is a GH-only issue, in which case ... I don't know enough to help. Good luck.

Comment: @r2evans I see now where i made a mistake.. At .gitattributes file i had this:            *.md linguist-language=R.